# Open pop-up window on submit using fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, paypal

The form that I have is as follow:

```
<form target="_floating" onsubmit="window.open('', '_floating', 'width=960px,height=480px')" method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="donpaypal" class="donations">
    /* Bunch of input not needed */
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" style="border: 0;" name="submit" onclick="sendEmailIframe(event, 1, 0);">
</form>
```

So what this does is that when I click on "submit" it opens a pop-window with the PayPal page for donations, I want to change that, instead of opening a window I'd like to open a pop-up just like the Fancybox does for images, the full html I have a few images which are open in a pop-up using the library of FancyBox, I don't have any more script in this page just that...
so how do I open that PayPal page in a pop-up using the FancyBox?
the syntax for my images is this:

```
<a href="media/gallery/c1635a2ff3b7ed914feb447c9696b67f.jpg" class="mod-view-box" onclick="return false;" id="2" rel="media-item">
    <img src="media/thumbnail/c1635a2ff3b7ed914feb447c9696b67f.jpg" title="pic2" name="thumnai" class="image">  
</a>
```

and the jquery to call the fancybox is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mod-view-box").fancybox();
    });
```

and that is how I open my images, but how do I open the paypal window using fancybox pop-up?...
**Edit**
The main idea of this is top trigger FancyBox's iFrame when click submit while using the method POST, in other words, when I click Submit it send's the user to another page I want to avoid that instead of going to another page open a pop-up with the post request... I'm not sure I made my self clear...

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a best approach but will work

Have a iframe in your page with paypal url on submit call fancy box with that.

Comment: The thing is that I'm doing a POST method, how can I do a post to an iFrame? ... but thanks

Comment: give me some time will post the code

Comment: I was thinking on how to use the inline java/jquery to trigger the fancybox ... as you can see I have the onsubmit="" in for form...